# What is proper convention for repeating tuples?

Tags: python, python-3.x, convention

**For lack of a better title, I want to find the most proper way to write `(0, 0, 0, 0)`.**

I am simply asking if `(0,) * 4` is acceptable, and should it be done?

Are there any specific cases for this?

What if it could be either RGB, or RGBA? Should I do `(0,) * n`?

If this were in a loop, how significant would the overhead be?

Thanks.

***Disclaimer:*** I am not asking for opinions, I am asking for a general consensus, or any **written specification**. Do not give your sole opinion without any support, or this post runs the risk of being closed due to going off-topic.

Comment: "Do not give your sole opinion without any support, or this post runs the risk of being closed due to going off-topic.": it's the question that's off topic and gets closed, not the answers.

Comment: If the tuple will always contain `int` objects, then the semantics are equivalent, but if the objects are mutable, then the semantics aren't necessarily equivalent.

Comment: I'm risking an opinion: `*` operator is _designed_ for those cases (immutable contents), so go ahead

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre I did say *this post*, I just want to make sure that the answers don't end up getting my question flagged.

Edit: Thanks for your real feedback (second comment).

Comment: you're welcome. Your question is on-topic. If answers are bad, the answers will be flagged, not your question. People know how to make the difference, don't worry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you had 100 zeroes to write in a tuple or list would you ask yourself this question?

Since the contents of the `tuple` are immutable elements, it's equivalent (it's faster to parse - see the end of the post - and the intent is clearer) to do `(0,) * 4` instead of `(0,0,0,0)`. It's beginning to become ridiculous for 2 elements but that's just my opinion :).

If the number increases it may save some precious debugging time because you missed one count/paste.

For mutable types [don't do that!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly), but you can do a similar thing: ex:

- `[[] for _ in range(n)]` for list of lists
- `tuple([] for _ in range(n))` for tuple of lists

Note that the `(0,)*n` form is definitely faster to parse. It's tricky to time such constructs because doing this naively skips the parsing part. But using evil `eval` helps in that case:

```
import time

n=100000

start_time = time.time()
for _ in range(n):
    eval("(0)*50")

print(time.time()-start_time)

fifty_zeros_tuple = "({})".format("0,"*50)  # generate (0,0,0,...) expression to pass to eval, not clocked to avoid bias

start_time = time.time()
for _ in range(n):
    eval(fifty_zeros_tuple)

print(time.time()-start_time)
```

no photo-finish on the results, `(0,)*50` is many times faster:

```
0.764380931854248
5.553457021713257
```

Comment: Also `timeit` can easily show that the exp: `python -m timeit 't = (0,)*4'` is almost the same as `python -m timeit 't = (0, 0, 0, 0)'` - so I think it's not arguable that using `(0,)*n` is not only fast but also practical!

Comment: @coder thanks for benching this. I was expecting that, because parsing (0,0,0,0) is probably slower (more characters ;))

Comment: Actually the speed seems to be the same for both cases but `(0,)*n` is a LOT more practical

Comment: would be interesting to try with n=100. But I'm too lazy to type 0, 100 times (that's the whole point BTW :))

Comment: I'm not sure that the parsing time is taken into account in timeit.

Comment: That's interesting..., I don't know that detail either, I just thought it would benchmark the time constructing the tuple

Comment: I tried with a simple `time.time` and same thing. That cannot be properly benched because it's converted to bytecode before timing is done. So (0,)*100 takes more time to execute. see my edit, I found a way and I'm right :)